# Unsolved references when importing typing using PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Using PyCharm, when trying to install List, Sequence, and Tuple from typing, they are all marked as unsolved references.  How do I fix this? I'm using Python 3.7

I've tried invalidating the cache but that didn't help.

The line that's not working is `from typing import List, Tuple, Sequence`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved - there was an old version of PyCharm installed

Answer (score 0):

You should check if it exists in *Project Window>External Libraries>Python 3.7>Lib*

Comment: It does exist there. Thank you though